# MySQLi: $mysqli->query will not insert, and no error is returned

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert simple data into my MySQL table via MySQLi, however it refuses to insert, with no error message reported.

**I'd like to stress that this query functions normally when entered directly into PhpMyAdmin (of course, with the variables replaced)**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
require_once('./inc/crypt.php');
require_once('./inc/mysql.php');

$privatekey = "-------------------------------- ";

$u = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$p = crypto($_POST['password']);
$e = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
      $_SESSION['loginError'] = "The captcha was entered incorrectly!";
      header("LOCATION: ./index.php?pg=1");
      die();
  }


$amt = 0;

if($data = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=?")){
    $data->bind_param("ss", $u, $e);
    $data->execute();
    $data->store_result();
    $amt = $data->num_rows();
    $data->close();
}
if($amt != 0){
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "A user has already registered with either that email or username.";
    header("LOCATION: ./index.php?pg=1");
    die();
}

if(strlen($u) < 5){
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "A username must be greater than 5 characters long.";
    header("LOCATION: ./index.php?pg=1");
    die();
}

if(strlen($e) <= 5){
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "An email must be greater than 5 characters long.";
    header("LOCATION: ./index.php?pg=1");
    die();
}

if(!strstr($e, "@")){
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "A valid email must be entered.";
    header("LOCATION: ./index.php?pg=1");
    die();
}

if(!ctype_alnum($u)){
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "Your username contains an invalid character.";
    header("LOCATION: ./index.php?pg=1");
    die();
}
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."r";

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`, `perms`, `ip`) VALUES ('".$u."', '".$p."', '".$e."', '0', '".$ip."')");


header("LOCATION: ./index.php?win=1");

?>
```

I also should note that using both $mysqli->query and prepared statements both did not work.

Here's my phpinfo() under the MySQLi section:

```
Client API library version  5.0.95
Client API header version   5.0.91
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
```

**Last thing: I have a very similar insert statement being used in a different file that works.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the rest of the PHP around your insert statement?

Comment: Ok, I just added a link to a gist of the entire script.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're not checking the return value of your `$mysqli->query` - try adding a call to `$mysqli->error` after that to see if there's an error.

Comment: I did, actually, but it still didn't return an error.

Comment: Are you using the same MySql user to connect from PHP that you are from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @brenhein - so what's the actual return value from `$mysqli->query`?

Comment: @Nilpo: No, but another insert statement on a different script, but using the same user works.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use single quotes instead use the ` likes this:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `perms`, `ip`) VALUES ('".$u."', '".$p."', '".$e."', '0', '".$ip."')");
```

It should not have the single quotes around the field names. I tested in phpMyAdmin and as your example showed it failed but with my example above it worked.

Comment: Why is your insert query all of the sudden look different from the original example? It clearly does not look like the image that you first provided. Now there before INSERT the double quote is missing and the single quotes was change to ` characters. Here the initial code: https://gist.github.com/40a945efb2d7cd6ed819

Comment: Because I was testing something before I posted this and forgot to undo the changes.

Comment: Well then with the new code, the reason why it's not working is because the double quote is missing before the `$mysqli->query(INSERT INTO` it should be `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO`